# Filtro por rango de fechas / laravel - controlador

Tags: sql, laravel, date, filtro

Esta function toma todas las publicaciones creadas y busca las que mas actividad ha tenido, busco que el filtro sea un poco mas especifico y solo muestre las mas activas pero de la semana anterior.

Archivo controlador de post **PostsController.php** - funciona pero muestra los post de mas actividad desde el origen de los tiempos

```
public function hot(){
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $date_ini = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date."- 1 day"));
    $date_final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date."- 1 week"));

    $hot_posts = Metric::with('post')
    ->select(array(DB::Raw('count(metrics.post_id) as count'), 'metrics.*'))
    ->groupBy('metrics.post_id')
    ->orderBy('count', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();

    return view('posts.hot', compact('hot_posts'));
}
```

**Ultima modificación que utilice**

```
public function hot(){
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $date_ini = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date."- 1 day"));
    $date_final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date."- 1 week"));

    $hot_posts = Metric::with('post')
    ->select(array(DB::Raw('count(metrics.post_id) as count'), 'metrics.*'))
    ->groupBy('created_at')
    ->having('created_at', '>=', $date_ini)
    ->groupBy('metrics.post_id')
    ->orderBy('count', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();

    return view('posts.hot', compact('hot_posts'));
}
```

Resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He utilizado estos metodos sin resultado

```
->where("metrics.created_at",">=",$date_ini)
->where("metrics.created_at","<=",$date_final)
->whereDate('created_at', ">=", '$date_ini')
->whereDate('created_at', "<=", '$date_final')
->whereBetween('created_at', [$date_ini, $date_final])
```

no se si de pronto es la posición o en que esta fallando

El orden de acciones que busco es

1. Cargar base de datos
2. Separar el grupo las resiente maximo 1 semana
3. Dentro del grupo que separo, los organice partiendo por quien tuvo mas actividad

Comment: Esto está mal `>having('created_at` ahí se debería usar un `where`

Comment: Jonathan muestranos por favor las relaciones definidas en tus modelos, creo que esta consulta se puede resolver mas fácilmente

Comment: Además explica por favor el resultado que deseas obtener por que ahi veo que tratas de hacer un conteo

Answer (score 1):

Pienso que estás intentando hacer una query del tipo:

```
SELECT post_id, count(*) as cantidad_metricas from metrics
 WHERE datediff(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), created_at)<7
 GROUP BY post_id
```

Y como en realidad necesitas los datos del post, la idea sería traerlos con algo como

```
SELECT post.id,
       post.title,
       count(*) as cantidad_metricas
  FROM metrics
  JOIN post on metrics.post_id = post.id
 WHERE datediff(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), metrics.created_at)<7
 GROUP BY (post_id,post_title)
```

Si esto se acerca a lo que tenías en mente, pienso que es un mal enfoque para trabajarlo en Eloquent, porque la relación anidada que traes al hacer

```
$hot_posts =  Metric::with('post')
```

No funciona igual que un join, y los métodos de conveniencia del ORM no te van a servir si empiezas a meterle consultas y subconsultas raw. Yo lo enfocaría al revés

```
$posts =  Post::withCount('metrics')
```

Que desde ya se trae el agregado de métricas cosa que no tengas que agruparlas a mano. Pero tú además necesitas contar solamente las métricas de la última semana, así que lo anterior se puede acotar como:

```
$posts = Post::withCount(['metrics' => function($query) {
   $query->where( <métricas de la última semana> );
}]);
```

La condición de "métricas de la última semana" no debieras hacerla armando cadenas en formato YYYY-MM-DD artesanalmente, deja que Eloquent haga ese trabajo (siempre y cuando `created_at` sea `datetime` o `timestamp`)

```
$posts = Post::withCount(['metrics' => function($query) {
   $query->where('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(7));
}]);
```

Esto añadiría a cada elemento del resultado un campo `metrics_count`. No puedes ordenar por él a nivel de consulta, así que no podrás usar `orderBy` con lo que además no tiene sentido usar `take(N)`.

Lo que se haría en este caso es traerse todos los resultados (lo cual entrega una colección)

```
$posts = Post::withCount([
   'metrics' => function($query) {
     $query->where('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(7));
   }
])->get();
```

Y esa colección la puedes ordenar y limitar a continuación

Como puede ser algo ineficiente, también puedes poner como cláusula que el post tenga métricas de la última semana, cosa de no ordenar sobre el universo de posts que de antemano puedes descartar:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('metrics', function($query) {
      $query->where('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(7));
})->withCount([
   'metrics' => function($query) {
        $query->where('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(7));
    }
])->get();
```

(nótese que el `whereHas` acepta un callback como segundo parámetro, mientras que el `withCount` requiere pasarle esa subquery como arreglo).

Lo que sale de esto ya es más manejable para ordenar:

```
$hot_posts = $posts->sortByDesc('metrics_count')->take(10);

return view('posts.hot', ['hot_posts'=>$hot_posts]);
```